# Creating file for internal storage returns Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, json, internal-storage

Hi I have a project that should save a JSON Array to internal storage. 
Here's my code:

```
public void createFile(String data){
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("userObj", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(data.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        Log.d(TAG, "Successfully created userObj file.");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to create userObj " + e);
    }
}
```

but when I'm calling `createFile(response);`
I'm getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:180)
```

Comment: You should show the code of openFileOutput.

Comment: And what does the stack trace look like? Are you sure `data` is not null?

Comment: you may be getting null response. Try complete stacktrace by `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Yes, either *data* or *fos* is null. please use debugger and check objects are properly created.

Comment: @JonSkeet data is not null.

Comment: @swapnil I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:180)

Comment: If you call `fileList`, does that throw a NullPointerException too?

Comment: @JonSkeet do you have any resolution for this? I just followed the documentation for writing file using internal storage http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: have you declared the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: @swapnil I write file to internal storage and not to external storage so I didn't declare WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: @AllenChun: Not yet, but I'm trying to help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. check whether you have the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE no matter you use internal storage or external storage.
2. check whether the file path is correct. You have to create the file path by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ()`

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:180

You don't have a valid `Context` you're working with.

Likely it's an `Activity` you have instantiated yourself with `new`. Don't do that. Activities should only by instantiated via an `Intent` by the framework. If you need to pass a `Context` around, pass a reference to a framework-initialized `Context` object such as an `Activity` around.